# Joomla htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess-configuration

I have some old links (old platform) and I want to redirect them to the new ones. I have both old and new links but I can figure it how to modify the **.htaccess** file. Everything I try causes a 500 error.

Here is my **.htaccess** file:

```
<IfModule autoindex>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Here is what I've added.

```
Redirect /index.php?c=newslist&id=12911 /news/article-name-etc-etc
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: In your redirect, try adding full path to new link like http://www.site.com/news/article-name-etc-etc

Comment: I tried that too :(

Answer (score 1):

Put this ABOVE your current htaccess lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /index.php /news/article-name-etc-etc?
```

- **RewriteEngine On** is always a requirement
- You need to put the command above because that first conditional in your code is messing with the index.php
- The **?** at the end of the new url strips the query strings.

This is a cool tool for tinkering with htaccess code: http://htaccess.mwl.be/